# Use SqlDataAdapter to fill a table in a dataset with a new name, code don't run completely and no error

Tags: c#, winforms, sqldataadapter

As you see, my code (it's in `myform_load`), when I run project, it continues to line `1.` Just not run other lines after that. I got no error, but the code doesn't run completely. After it come to line one, `myform` is shown. Where is the problem?

```
SqlDataAdapter userSharj_history;
private void myform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         con.Open();
         using (userSharj_history = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM users_sharj WHERE user_id = {0} AND datetime BETWEEN '{1}%' AND '{2}%'", user_id, az_tarikh_globalizationDateTimePicker1.Text, ta_tarikh_globalizationDateTimePicker1.Text), con))
         {
1.           userSharj_history.Fill(nan_DataSet, "sharjes");
2.           gridControl1.DataSource = nan_DataSet.Tables["sharjes"];
         }
         con.Close();
    }
    view_btn.Focus();
}
```

- The Query string is fine. I tested it in [GUI Query Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Query_Tool#GUI_Query_Builder).
- I use this `dataset` in my main form that call this form and there is no table in it with the name `sharjes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either check the Output window or enable reporting of all exceptions. Visual Studio will not inform you about many exceptions by default.

Go to menu *Debug* --> *Exceptions...* and then tick *Thrown for Common language runtime Exceptions* and click OK. Run your code again and see if it throws an exception now.

Comment: that was helpful, thanks. i just tick all in Common language runtime Exceptions and i got my problem, how can i set ticks to default again ?

Comment: Reset All button should do it.